# No puedo ejecutar NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, npm

Tengo una falla en npm, la situación es la siguiente:

He instalado *NodeJS* para trabajar un proyecto en *Angular*, instalé *LTS 6.10.3* y *nmp 3.10.10*.

Ejecuté lo siguiente:

```
node -v npm -v
```

... y cuando le doy `npm -v` me sale un error antes de mostrarme la versión que dice:

```
npm -v
```

> `CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node,exe" "C;\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g` no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable. 3.10.10

He desinstalado *Node* muchas veces, limpiando las carpeta en **%user%/appdata/npm** y **npm-cache**, lo he instalado como administrador,
aunque el usuario con el que trabajo es administrador, y el error permanece.

Al principio pensé que era solo un error no fatal pues al final muestra la versión pero cada vez que intento instalar un paquete con `-g`, por ejemplo:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

... al final saca error en rojo y no termina de instalar.

Pasa lo mismo con todos los paquetes.

Adjunto la última parte del registro con los errores que genera:

> 85429 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
>   85429 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>   85430 verbose pkgid node-sass@4.5.2
>   85431 verbose cwd D:\npm
>   85432 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
>   85433 error argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
>   85434 error node v6.10.3
>   85435 error npm  v3.10.10
>   85436 error code ELIFECYCLE
>   85437 error node-sass@4.5.2 install: 'node scripts/install.js'
>   85437 error Exit status -4058
>   85438 error Failed at the node-sass@4.5.2 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
>   85438 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
>   85438 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
>   85438 error not with npm itself.
>   85438 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
>   85438 error     node scripts/install.js
>   85438 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
>   85438 error     npm bugs node-sass
>   85438 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
>   85438 error     npm owner ls node-sass
>   85438 error There is likely additional logging output above.
>   85439 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Ejecuté `npm install` como administrador y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Puedes intentar instalar otra versión y usar otra ruta de instalación. También puedes usar `nvm` y probar diferentes versiones.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes agregar al path

```
;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
```

y probar.

Reiniciar el comando y poner `npm -v`

Answer (score 0):

hace días me paso lo mismo pero para utilizar Nodejs y aplicarlo con Angular tienes que usar la versión 10.13.0 sino este se sacara error o si vas a utilizar Nodejs y vas a generar el package.json necesitas la versión 11.2.0 (incluye npm 6.4.1)

Ve a la pagina y descarga los ejecutables.
Tarde la respuesta pero llego.